# Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS Install: stuck on step "ubuntu ubiquity: Processing triggers for libgk-pixbuf2.0-0 ..."

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, lts

I'm installing Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS for the first time and the Install is stuck on the progress command:

ubuntu ubiquity: Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 ...

This has been stuck for several hours now. But I can browse the internet fine on the computer (the OS is installed enough to let me do that). So it's not an internet connection. What should I do?

Comment: Hi Mikhail -sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common - also  have a look at this answer about installing those packages manually then run an update afterwards to see if there are other issues - https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2023348

Comment: @Gadgetroid please turn your comment into an answer

Comment: @ ubashu - done as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common - also have a look at this answer about installing those packages manually then run an update afterwards to see if there are other issues - [UbuntuForums Thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2023348)